# Laravel Queues Doc. - Passing an Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-queue

There is a statement I don't understand in Queues chapter of Laravel's 5.5 documentation. It says:

> If your queued job accepts an Eloquent model in its constructor, only
>   the identifier for the model will be serialized onto the queue.

I want to understand what this means. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should read further:

> When the job is actually handled, the queue system will automatically re-retrieve the full model instance from the database. It's all totally transparent to your application and prevents issues that can arise from serializing full Eloquent model instances.

what means that if you pass to Queue user with id 1 and something will be changed before executing job than when executing this job, those changes will be available because fresh model will be taken from database.

Comment: This is not my case in redis, I don't know but when I dispatched a job to the queue then made some changes in the model. Once the queue unserializes it, it still uses the cached model.